# Set background image and color in css

Tags: html, css

I'm going to set background image and background color both this is working fine but the problem is that when I write some text on a `div` the background automatically apply on the text here is my code please review it.

```css
#canvas-preview {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('path/to/image.png');
}
#canvas-preview::before {
  background-color: green;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#custom-canvas {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas-preview">
  <div id="custom-canvas">There is some text</div>
</div>
```

I want to set text color white. What's the problem with this code.

**UPDATE**

I need both `background-image` and `background-color`.
For example green color over the image with `opacity: 0.37`
Sorry, I forgot the placing `opacity` property in `css`

```
  #canvas-preview::before {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.37;   /* editing in code */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I need both things not one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `z-index:-1;` to your pseudo element `#canvas-preview::before` to make visible the *Text*

As it comes over the `#canvas-preview` as a layer and works as *fallback* in case your *bg-image* won't load.

So to make visible the text-layer over that you need to lower the `z-index` of your *pseudo* element.

### Updated Code Snippet

```css
#canvas-preview {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1463950922781-0e6d07cbd146);
}
#canvas-preview::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#custom-canvas {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas-preview">
  <div id="custom-canvas">There is some text</div>
</div>
```

> Instead of adding `opacity` I would suggest to use *alpha* value of the *bg-color*`(rgba)` in your `pseudo` element which will be a better solution.

Comment: please see the updation

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and text is white. It is just hidden behind this green container because of this:

```
 #canvas-preview::before
```

If you remove before thing(just for test purposes) you will see that text is white. So You need a different approach. Code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#canvas-preview{
        width:200px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=8c1c8cba242e');
  
    }
    #canvas-preview::before{
        background-color:green;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
       z-index:-99999; // add z-index in this css code.
    }
    #custom-canvas{
        margin:10px;
        color:#fff;
      
    }
```

```html
    <div id="canvas-preview">
            <div id="custom-canvas">There is some text</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: simple `-1` will be more than enough, there's no need to waste your `z-index` value ;)

Comment: please see the updation

Comment: @AzeemHaider well the above code shows both background img and background color.

Answer (score 0):

The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than static (the default).

[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) :

Your code should change like this:

```
#canvas-preview::before{
 background-color:green;
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 z-index:-1;
}
#custom-canvas{
 margin:10px;
 color:#fff;
}
```

This may be helpful.